# Sending large email attachments with actionmailer and heroku from s3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, smtp, actionmailer, email-attachments, sendgrid

i have an app that stores uploaded files in s3, once complete a mail is sent with the attached file. The app works fine when attachments are between 0-15 Mb in size. However when i attached something larger like 16 Mb it fails and returns the error:

**Net::SMTPFatalError: 550 Could not send e-mail, max size of 20480000 bytes exceeded**

1). Firstly i do not understand why it fails as, 16Mb **<** 20480000 bytes(+/-19 Mb)
2). How can i mail files larger than 19Mb

I am using heroku's sendgrid addon, and rails 3 with amazon s3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Normally when you attach a binary file to a mail message it gets translated to an ASCII format, and the size grows with about 30% - in your situation that means the maximum file attachment can have somewhere between 15 and 16M.

Comment: thanks, is it possible to send larger file attachments somehow from my app?

Comment: It all depends on the configuration of the mail server. Gmail for example allows messages up to 25M, which means binary attachments of up to 19M. There is not much you can do in your application.